# How to traverse xml file in Mulesoft

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing, mule, mulesoft

In my input payload I will get value Username=erepair, Password=erepairtest and InterfaceName=ABC.
I need to check all these value exist under the particular partner node in a partner.xml file under scr/main/resource.

Basically the need is to check if the Interface "ABC" is authorized for erepair/erepairtest

```
    <PartnerMain>
        <Partner>
            <userName>erepair</userName>
            <userPassword>erepairtest</userPassword>
            <AuthorizedInterface>
                <name>ABC</name>
            </AuthorizedInterface>
            <AuthorizedInterface>
                <name>EFG</name>
            </AuthorizedInterface>
        </Partner>
        <Partner>
            <userName>pair</userName>
            <userPassword>pairtest</userPassword>
            <AuthorizedInterface>
                <name>ABC</name>
            </AuthorizedInterface>
            <AuthorizedInterface>
                <name>EFG</name>
            </AuthorizedInterface>
        </Partner>
    </PartnerMain>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are going to use Mule 4.x runtime and thus DataWeave 2.0

You can apply a [filter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-filter) to the incoming input payload and check for the conditions to match.

For e.g. Lets say you have the variables containing the userName, password and InterfaceName ( since i am using playground and i wanted to show you a quick solution to the problem at hand). Lets say your payload is the partner.xml file (since you would be implementing this in a Mule flow, you would use a file:read operation and refer to it in the Dataweave Transform Message component.).

The script to check the fields against the payload would look something like this:

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var userName="erepair"
var password="erepairtest"
var interfaceName="ABC"
---
(payload.PartnerMain.*Partner filter (($.userName == userName) and ($.userPassword == password) and ($.AuthorizedInterface.*name contains interfaceName)))[0]
```

**Input**

```
<PartnerMain>
        <Partner>
            <userName>erepair</userName>
            <userPassword>erepairtest</userPassword>
            <AuthorizedInterface>
                <name>ABC</name>
            </AuthorizedInterface>
            <AuthorizedInterface>
                <name>EFG</name>
            </AuthorizedInterface>
        </Partner>
        <Partner>
            <userName>pair</userName>
            <userPassword>pairtest</userPassword>
            <AuthorizedInterface>
                <name>ABC</name>
            </AuthorizedInterface>
            <AuthorizedInterface>
                <name>EFG</name>
            </AuthorizedInterface>
        </Partner>
    </PartnerMain>
```

**Output**

```
{
  "userName": "erepair",
  "userPassword": "erepairtest",
  "AuthorizedInterface": {
    "name": "ABC"
  },
  "AuthorizedInterface": {
    "name": "EFG"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure..Please accept the answer so that others can make use of the same in future.